# Unknown parameter in input: "WaiterConfig", must be one of: StackName, NextToken

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

Trying to create a stack with `boto3`, and on the `Waiter` I get a failure:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "WaiterConfig", must be one of: StackName, NextToken
```

I initialize the waiter like this:

```
client = boto3.client('cloudformation',
                      aws_access_key_id=os.environ["AWS_ID"],
                      aws_secret_access_key=os.environ["AWS_KEY"]
)

waiter = client.get_waiter('stack_create_complete')

waiter.wait(
    StackName=os.environ["SYSTEM_NAME"],
    NextToken=os.environ["SYSTEM_NAME"], // I think this param is wrong.
    WaiterConfig={
        'Delay': 123,
        'MaxAttempts': 123
    }
)
```

An empty string doesn't work; neither does simply putting in the only stack's name.

***I'm only creating one stack, what goes in `NextStack`?***